# windows scheduler not executing my python script - why?

Tags: python, scheduler

I have written my first script that I want to run daily from Windows Scheduler on my computer. The script is to 1) determine today's sunrise and sunset times and, 2)adjust laptop's screen brightness accordingly.

I know the script works because when I execute it manually either in a terminal or through launching a batch file, it works perfectly. But when I try to set up my Windows Scheduler to trigger it, nothing happens. Also, even when I click run from the Scheduler window rather than wait for its trigger time, it says its running but nothing happens. I expect to see the screen brightness gradually increase if its running during daylight hours.

brightness.pyw:

```
# importing the module
import screen_brightness_control as sbc
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
import json
import requests
import sys
from suntime import Sun
import time

send_url = "http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=68d6a43e7f37d2152f9bb7dc199b87ef"
geo_req = requests.get(send_url)
geo_json = json.loads(geo_req.text)
latitude = geo_json['latitude']
longitude = geo_json['longitude']

sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)

today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()

print(today_sr)
print(today_ss)

while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    if today_ss > current_time > today_sr and sbc.get_brightness() != 100:
        sbc.fade_brightness(100, interval=5)
    elif current_time > today_ss and sbc.get_brightness() != 0:
        sbc.fade_brightness(0, interval=5)
        sys.exit()
    time.sleep(60)
```

run_brightness_python.bat

```
"C:\Users\dannl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\dannl\scripts\brightness.pyw"
pause
```

screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [su] is probably a better place to ask about using the Windows Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this, my problem was that I needed to check the "Run only when user is logged on" box. I have no idea why that needed to be checked to work but it fixed the issue.